# The tag [número-gramatical] wasn't showing up as a suggestion

Tags: bug, estado-no-reproducido, etiquetas

I was trying to add [número-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%bamero-gramatical) to [an old question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3988/9385), and no matter what I typed in the tag input area, I could not get this tag to come up as a suggestion.  I tried the first part, I tried the second part, I tried English, I tried Spanish, nothing worked.  I know that the tag suggestions are limited to five.  That wasn't the problem, though, as sometimes I got zero or one suggestion, but not the one I was looking for -- which did reliably come up if I went directly to the [Tags page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags) to look for it there.

Is this a bug?

Comment: the question already has the tag [tag:número-gramatical].

Comment: @fedorqui - Sorry I wasn't clear.  I was able to crowbar it in by pretending to reinvent the tag.  That is, I finally typed in the whole tag (all seven syllables).  The bug I think I found was that no matter what I tried, I couldn't get that tag to come up in the list of suggested tags.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPXtP.gif

Comment: @fedorqui - Interesting.  I just tried to add this tag to a randomly chosen question and, same as you, was not able to reproduce the bug.  Perhaps the system needed to be primed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75967/discussion-on-question-by-aparente001-the-tag-numero-gramatical-wasnt-showing).